# What is the difference between subroutines and scripts in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am in the midst of learning Perl, and I have encountered a question. What, exactly is the difference between subroutines and scripts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A **script** is just a name for a (usually short) program usually contained in a single file. It's not really a scientific/technical term and therefore is pretty vague - people can refer to a "script" when discussing a 3-line quick program, or a 10000 lines of code program.

Some people refer to ANY Perl program as a "script" - see below for the historical reason. Some people, when they say "a Perl script" as opposed to a Perl "program", mean a relatively simple, relatively short program, frequently structured without using any subroutines/classes/other methods of code organization. Again, there's no standard definition.

As an aside, the reason why Perl programs are frequently called "scripts" is that Perl [originally was used for writing scripts that perform work in Unix shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language#General-purpose_dynamic_languages), the way shell scripting languages were used. The term "[scripting language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language)" means a language used to control an application, in this case Unix shell.

Of course, since then Perl has grown to become a full fledged programming language, but the word/term remained, sometimes used by inertia, sometimes derogatorily.

---

A [**subroutine**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine) (also known as a procedure, function, routine, method, or subprogram) is a portion of code within a larger program that performs a specific task and is relatively independent of the remaining code. It is frequently meant to contain code that performs the task which needs to be done several times in your program, or even by multiple programs.

A subroutine is NOT a Perl specific concept, though calling it "subroutine" is done in very few languages (most use the term function, method or procedure).

---

*As a special side note, a "**method**" - in Perl as well as other languages - is a special type of subroutine which is associated with an object oriented class or an object of that class. The fact that it's merely a special case of a subroutine is, of course, highlighted by the fact that - despite [deepest wishes by "Modern Perl" author chromatic](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2011/01/adding-a-method-keyword-to-perl-5.html) - methods in Perl 5 are declared with "sub" keyword, same as regular subroutines.*

---

As noted above, **some** people, when referring to a Perl program as a "script", imply that it does not contain subroutines (e.g. anything complicated enough to have a subroutine is no longer a "script" but a "program"). But that is not an accepted or formal definition - as stated, there **is no definition of what a script is**, everyone uses the term any which way they want.

Comment: "Subroutine" and "method" are not interchangeable, despite two implications that they are. A method is a subroutine associated with a class and/or object.

Comment: @ikegami - That's correct in Perl. I'm not certain about other languages

Comment: Not just Perl. Method is a general OOP term. I have no heard of any languages that have misappropriated it.

Comment: @ikegami - added. If some other language's expert comments here stating that it's not the case for their language I'll amend appropriately later.

Answer (score 1):

A script is usually a file, which can contain statements and subroutines. A subroutine is something you find *within* a script.

Subroutines are described in detail in the [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) manual page.

Comment: A script *can* be a file, but it does not *have to* be a file. Say rather that it is a collection of code that performs a specific, smaller task, most often contained in a single file.

Comment: I'm not going for a formal definition of what a *script* is. I'll change my answer to be more vague.

Comment: It's probably best not to get too philosophical. :)

Comment: @TLP - too late. I [did](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9372509/119280), I'm afraid :(

Comment: @DVK You obviously have never debated with a philosopher. =) I was thinking more along the lines of "Is it an idea or more of a physical entity? What is software?" ;)